# Helm - Spark operator examples/spark-pi.yaml does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I've deployed Spark Operator to GKE using the [Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/sparkoperator) to a custom namespace:

```
helm install --name sparkoperator incubator/sparkoperator --namespace custom-ns --set sparkJobNamespace=custom-ns
```

and confirmed the operator running in the cluster with `helm status sparkoperator`.

However when I'm trying to run the Spark Pi example `kubectl apply -f examples/spark-pi.yaml` I'm getting the following error:

```
the path "examples/spark-pi.yaml" does not exist
```

There are few things that I probably still don't get:

1. Where is actually `examples/spark-pi.yaml` located after deploying the operator?
2. What else should I check and what other steps should I take to make the example work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the `spark-pi.yaml` file [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/examples/spark-pi.yaml).

You should copy it to your filesystem, customize it if needed, and provide a valid path to it with `kubectl apply -f path/to/spark-pi.yaml`.

Comment: What if I have a file stored in Google Storage `gs://my-bucket/spark-pi.yaml`. How should I properly access it with `kubectl apply -f ....` ? Now I'm getting an error that the path is invalid, however it exists

Comment: You cannot refer that file with the default installation of kubectl CLI. In order to do that you need to find the appropriate plugin or extension for the kubectl CLI or patch it on your own. Though you can refer files accessible by `http`.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl apply` needs a yaml file either locally on the system where you are running kubectl command or it can be a `http/https` endpoint hosting the file.